# How do I access selected dates in a Calendar control in my viewmodel?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn.Micro.  The `SelectionMode` for my calendar control is `MultipleRange`.

I see a `SelectedDate` property that I could create a binding for, which I could access in my ViewModel.  I also see `SelectedDates`, but when I try to create a binding for that, such as:

```xaml
<Calendar x:Name="Dates"
          SelectedDates="{Binding SelectedDates}"
          SelectionMode="MultipleRange"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

it tells me that "`SelectedDates` property is read-only and cannot be set from markup."

Is there a solution for this?  How do I access the selected dates in a Calendar control from my ViewModel, hopefully using Caliburn.Micro's conventions?

Comment: You might get more views if you add the C# or VB.NET tag (whichever is appropriate to your project).

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same situation. I simply connected the SelectedDatesChanged event to a public method with the parameter set to SelectedDates. Here's the XAML:

```
<Calendar Name="TournamentCalendar" SelectionMode="MultipleRange" Margin="5">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedDatesChanged">
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="AssignDates">
                <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding SelectedDates, ElementName=TournamentCalendar}"/>
             </cal:ActionMessage>
        </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Calendar>
```

In my view model, I added the following method. Please note the type of the parameter.

```
public void AssignDates(SelectedDatesCollection dates)
{
    if (dates.Count > 0)
    {
        _tournamentDates.Clear();
        foreach (var date in dates)
        {                  
            _tournamentDates.Add(new DateViewModel(date));
        }
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TournamentDates);
    }
}
```

I also discovered that you can actually update the selected dates from the view model once this method is called by simply adding or removing date(s) from the incoming SelectedDatesCollection object as follows:

```
public void AssignDates(SelectedDatesCollection dates)
{
    if (dates.Count > 0)
    {
        // Removes today if included then adds a date 4 days from today
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        if (dates.Contains(today))
        {
           dates.Remove(today);
        }
        dates.Add(today.AddDays(4));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Where does <cal:ActionMessage come from?

Comment: I believe he's using Caliburn in his example

Comment: @evilfish Caliburn's page about Actions https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you will need to create your own attached property. People have had the exact same problem with the SelectedItems property on the ListBox (etc).

Here's an example of a solution you might try:
http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/02/how-to-databind-to-selecteditems.html

This is what I have done in the past. It allows you to stay true to the MVVM pattern, but it is quite a lot of extra code. You might need to balance the value of MVVM against the additional cost of development and maintenance.